# asp.net button causes posts back but doesn't fire event

Tags: asp.net, onclick, postback

I have an ASP button on my page that is supposed to trigger an event on post back.  This used to work but has stopped working on every single page that the search form is on.  This particular code has not been updated since I got it all set up and working.  The button code looks like:

```
<asp:Button id="search_button" class="search_button" runat="server" OnClick="search_button_click" />
```

And the post back event code looks like:

```
    protected void search_button_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SessionHandler.sqlSearchTerm = searchBox.Text;

        if (Int32.Parse(searchCatDdl.SelectedValue.ToString()) > 0)
        {
            SessionHandler.search_mcat_id = searchCatDdl.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            SessionHandler.search_mcat_id = "0";
        }

        Response.Redirect("/search.aspx");
        Response.End();
    }
```

I tried replacing the code inside of the event with just `Response.Write("Hit");`, but it never triggered at all.  The page does post back though.  There are no extra `</form>` tags on the page (or any page), leaving just one open form tag and one closing form tag.  And like I said, this used to work but now is not.

The only code in the `Page_Load` method is code that creates drop down options for the search form (which has always worked and still does).  There's nothing that would end the output or functionality.  I'm trying to get debugging ideas as to how to figure out why this would stop working.  I've tried to get the ID of the object used to cause post back but it's coming up blank.  Then again, maybe I'm doing it wrong.  In the `Page_Load` method, I did something along the lines of `Request["__(something)"];'.  I don't remember exactly what it was, but it was setting that to a string variable which was supposed to have the object ID in it.  Anyway, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I also want to point out that if I change the `OnClick` attribute of my button to something that does not exist, it does err out.  So it seems as if things are set correctly as I have them (to me, anyway).  Also, every other control on the site still works and fires it's post back event.

Here is the panel my control is in:

```
<asp:Panel cssClass="search_items" id="pnlSearchButton" runat="server" DefaultButton="search_button">
    <div class="search_bar">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="200"><h3 class="title">auction items</h3></td>
                <td width="230"><asp:TextBox ID="searchBox" runat="server" placeholder="Search" name="search" /></td>
                <td width="220">
                    <div class="select_cont option-set" id="filters">
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="searchCatDdl" cssClass="option-set clearfix"  data-filter-group="selectset">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="70"><asp:Button id="search_button" cssClass="search_button" runat="server" OnClick="search_button_click" /></td>
                <td>
                    <a class="search_icon icon_collapse" id="toggle4"></a>
                    <div class="search_icon divider"></div>
                    <a href="#" class="search_icon icon_gridview" id="toggle6">&nbsp;</a> 
                    <a href="#" class="search_icon icon_listview" id="toggle5">&nbsp;</a>
                    <div class="search_icon divider"></div>
                    <a href="/search.aspx?adv=1" class="search_icon icon_advanced">&nbsp;</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

At the top of my page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/master-pages/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="HeaderFooter.master.cs" Inherits="master_pages.HeaderFooter" %>
```

The entire code behind for this particular page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CowansRedesign.master_pages
{
    public partial class HeaderFooter : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["logout"]))
                {
                    SessionHandler.mailId = "";
                    SessionHandler.mailName = "";
                    SessionHandler.mailFirstName = "";
                }

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SessionHandler.mailId) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(SessionHandler.mailFirstName) && Request.ServerVariables["SCRIPT_NAME"].ToString() != "/default.aspx")
                {
                    if (hiName != null) {
                        hiName.Text = "Hi " + SessionHandler.mailFirstName;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!IsPostBack && searchCatDdl != null)
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> mainCatList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                mainCatList.Add("0", "All Categories");

                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["wesdb1SQL"].ToString()))
                using (SqlCommand strSQL = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    strSQL.CommandText = "Select mcat_id, mcat_name " +
                                         "From tblMcat " +
                                         "ORDER BY mcat_name ASC";

                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader itemReader = strSQL.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (itemReader.Read())
                            {
                                mainCatList.Add(itemReader["mcat_id"].ToString(), itemReader["mcat_name"].ToString());
                            }
                            itemReader.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e1.ToString());
                        //Response.Write(e.ToString());
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }

                searchCatDdl.DataSource = mainCatList;
                searchCatDdl.DataTextField = "Value";
                searchCatDdl.DataValueField = "Key";
                searchCatDdl.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void overlay_itemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                bool isSaleOnline = Public.isSaleOnline(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "EventSaleId").ToString());
                bool isSaleLotted = Public.isSaleLotted(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "EventSaleId").ToString());
                Image overlayImage = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("overlayImage");
                HyperLink auctionLink = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("viewAuction");
                HyperLink regLink = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("viewReg");
                HyperLink catalogLink = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("viewCatalog");
                Label slide_date = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("slide_date");
                Label EventName = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("EventName");

                EventName.Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "EventName").ToString();

                overlayImage.ImageUrl = "http://cowansauctions.com/webimages/events/" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "EventMain");

                string[] formats = { "MM/dd/yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss" };
                IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);

                DateTime formattedDate;

                //Response.Write(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "homeDate").ToString());
                //Response.End();

                DateTime.TryParseExact(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "homeDate").ToString(), formats, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out formattedDate);

                slide_date.Text = String.Format("{0:MM.dd.yy}", formattedDate);

                if (DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "EventSaleId").ToString().Length >= 1)
                {
                    auctionLink.Text = "More about the auction&nbsp;>";
                    auctionLink.NavigateUrl = "/auctions/details.aspx?id=" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "EventId");

                    if (isSaleOnline)
                    {
                        catalogLink.Text = "View Catalog&nbsp;>";
                        catalogLink.NavigateUrl = "/auctions/catalog.aspx?id=" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "EventSaleId") + "" + (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "EventStartPage").ToString()) ? "&page=" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "EventStartPage") : "");

                        regLink.Text = "Register to bid online&nbsp;>";
                        regLink.NavigateUrl = "/auctions/live-bid.aspx";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "EventRegister")))
                        {
                            regLink.Text = "Register to bid online&nbsp;>";
                            regLink.NavigateUrl = "/auctions/live-bid.aspx";
                        }

                        if (isSaleLotted)
                        {
                            catalogLink.Text = "View Catalog&nbsp;>";
                            catalogLink.NavigateUrl = "/auctions/catalog.aspx?id=" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "EventSaleId") + "" + (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "EventStartPage").ToString()) ? "&page=" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "EventStartPage") : "");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    catalogLink.Text = "View Event Details&nbsp;>";
                    catalogLink.NavigateUrl = "/event.aspx?id=" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "EventId");

                    auctionLink.Visible = false;
                    regLink.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }

        protected void search_button_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SessionHandler.sqlSearchTerm = searchBox.Text;

            if (Int32.Parse(searchCatDdl.SelectedValue.ToString()) > 0)
            {
                SessionHandler.search_mcat_id = searchCatDdl.SelectedValue.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                SessionHandler.search_mcat_id = "0";
            }

            Response.Redirect("/search.aspx");
            Response.End();
        }

        public static string StripHTML(string htmlString)
        {
            string pattern = @"<(.|\n)*?>";

            return Regex.Replace(htmlString, pattern, string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess it it is a page life cycle related issue, my suggestion would be to switch to the MVC model instead of Forms, but that may not be an option. :)

Comment: @ShaneKenyon I actually don't know how to do that anyway.  I tried Google-ing it but just got results about database stuff.  But yeah, the entire website is done, this issue just cropped up out of nowhere.

Comment: One thing I've seen a lot of people mention is setting CausesValidation to false.  Again, this "fix" would point to some other page lifecycle issue I'd think.  Also I saw reference to people running into this due to copy-paste of code from one page to another, which could break the bindings, not sure if this applies here.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Not nearly enough info here to diagnose the actual issue.

Comment: Have you tried using the browser debug window (or Fiddler) to see what response is coming back from the server ? Also - and I know it used to work fine but isn't now - can you remove OnClick="search_button_click" from the markup, and wire up the click event in PageInit - does that make any difference ?

Comment: @ShaneKenyon I tried setting the button attribute `CausesValidation` to `false`, but that did not work.  Thanks though.

Comment: @sh1rts Not sure if I've done this right, but I removed the `OnClick` attribute and added `search_button.Click += new EventHandler(search_button_click);` in my `Page_Load` method.  Nothing happened when clicked.

Comment: @lincolnk I understand you wouldn't be able to tell me exactly what my issue is here, but I don't know what code would be relevant to show.  I'm just wondering if there are some common reasons something like this would occur.  If you would like to see some additional code, though, just let me know what parts and I will add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally found the issue.  I was thinking back and realized the very last change I made was adding Google's Tag Manager code to the website for some SEO tracking.  That code turned out to be what was causing this one thing to stop working.  I have no clue why.  I removed it and everything is working.

```
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-5XQX2B"
    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-fdsafdsa');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Comment: Strange.. btw, attaching an event handler should be done before PageLoad, PageInit is more appropriate. I wire handlers up this way to avoid polluting the markup, but that's just my preference. Glad you found an answer to your problem !

Comment: @sh1rts Yes, I was reading that same thing too.  I don't usually program in ASP/C# so I'm not too familiar with it.  Just enough to cause trouble.  haha~

Comment: This killed our website last night. No postbacks from asp.net buttons. I have no idea what part of the google tagmanager caused it, but I suspect it was an issue with IE8. Due to mootools not working with the ajax update panel in a late(ish) version we left it at a version that worked. This forced us to use the emulate ie8 tag at the top of the page. With that emulate in, google tag manager broke the site, removing it allowed postback, but the mootools parts broke. .. due to the way our site works we needed to toss the google tagmanager code. I suspect that google hates ie <9 so no support.

Comment: Nobody have a better answer for people who do have to keep GTM in their applications? I manage an old Asp.Net application and cannot migrate it.