# google tag manager breaking asp.net postbacks

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have added the GTM code exactly as indicated in the product page, the javascript in the head area and the noscript in the body, making sure the container id is there.

my asp.net/dotnetnuke website works perfectly without this code, but as soon as I add it, a lot of my controls (that have code behind) start acting strangely

e.g. a dropdownlist value is selected, and then all page's dropdownlists now show empty values

I have seen that I am not alone, and found at least two other SO posts around this,

[Issue with GTM and asp.net webforms with two submit buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41717000/issue-with-gtm-and-asp-net-webforms-with-two-submit-buttons)

[asp.net button causes posts back but doesn't fire event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616966/asp-net-button-causes-posts-back-but-doesnt-fire-event)

cross posting in GTM group,

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/KXbi6oUnGnw;context-place=forum/tag-manager

I am double and triple checking what I can do on my own code to try and fix this, but it looks like it could be an issue with GTM itself

help is appreciated.

example of controls immediately after the postback (all ddls are now empty)

[image]

**Edit:**

browser console has no errors or warnings

not all ddls have issues. below is an example (appears to be related to those with code behind/updates)

working ddl

```
<select name="dnn$ctr559$ViewPesquisaHome$ddlNegocio_smallSearch" id="dnn_ctr559_ViewPesquisaHome_ddlNegocio_smallSearch" class="input-large"> </select>
```

non working ddl

```
<select name="dnn$ctr559$ViewPesquisaHome$ddlConcelho_smallSearch" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'dnn$ctr559$ViewPesquisaHome$ddlConcelho_smallSearch\',\'\')', 0)" id="dnn_ctr559_ViewPesquisaHome_ddlConcelho_smallSearch" class="input-large">
</select>
```

Comment: In the developer tools of your browser, you may be showing an error, can you share an image?

Comment: console is clear white throughout the tests. answer updated

Comment: I have the same issue. My EventTarget value is lost in the postback when I add GTM. It start to work again if I remove GTM.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  We just upgraded to GTM and experiencing the same thing.  Uggghhh.  GTM has been a mess already and now this.  Why Google?  Why?